# Always execute 2 (or more) commands in one line, but return the exit status of 1st one

Tags: bash

Is it possible to execute 2 or more commands in one line but return the status of the 1st command in bash?

I have the following step in Docker build:

```
RUN bin/myserver && cat tmp/log && rm -rf tmp
```

It is essential to run that process inside my docker build, and it makes sense to make a cleanup afterwards to remove unneeded things to be stored as docker layer.

The myserver logs to log file, not console output, so I need to cat the log to know what was going on, especially in case of failure.

How can I put those things together?

Comment: I'm not sure you've understood what the `&&` operator is doing here. Chaining commands with `&&` means that the right-hand command will only be executed if the left-hand one returns `0`. So, if `bin/myserver` fails and therefore returns something other than `0`, then `cat` won't run and so cannot log why.

Comment: Why don't you mount `tmp/log` as a volume when you want to debug?

Comment: @TomFenech the docker build is run in gitlab build, where one failed command stop the whole build so I would have no use from it afterwards. I need to do that as single liner...

Comment: Does `bni/myserver` run as a daemon (hence the command exits immediately with the server running in the background)? Or, in normal circumstances, is it expected to exit?

Comment: @glennjackman this is what makes me worry if I should post the details why I need such behavior, to prevent off topics. It is expect to exit when it makes its job during build time,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
RUN sh -c 'bin/myserver; status=$?; cat tmp/log; rm -rf tmp; exit $status'
```

Comment: A charm is here 'sh -c'. I've tried with 'exit $status' on my own and I get thrown out of my shell ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the stderr of a command using **2>**

To ignore the errors, you can redirect it to /dev/null: **2> /dev/null**

So your command line becomes:

```
RUN bin/myserver && cat tmp/log 2> /dev/null && rm -rf tmp 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood me. My myserver logs to file, not to stderr/stdin. And it fails with error status, so 2nd command would be never called in case of failure.